# Encrypted databags in chef-environments

Tags: chef-infra, environments, databags

We manage some critical information in encrypted databags, e.g. the ssl certificates: `databags/ssl`.

We'd prefer to only give a very limited set of people access to the secret that decrypts these encrypted databags to avoid having our private keys all over the place. Only the people knife-bootstrapping and deploying servers with that, should have access.

Databags are not limited to an `environment` but are global. So we either have to make our recipes toggle on environments and pick different databags, or we'd need to encrypt a part of the databag: [only certain entries](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials%5fdata%5fbags.html#with-environments):

```
{
  "id": "some_data_bag_item",
  "production" : {
    # Hash with all your data here
  },
  "testing" : {
    # Hash with all your data here
  }
}

bag_item[node.chef_environment]["some_other_key"]
```

How do you manage your encrypted data-bags? Where do you keep the secret and how do you avoid having to hand out the secret to anyone working on chef?

Comment: Have you had a look at [chef-vault](https://github.com/Nordstrom/chef-vault)?

Comment: I have glanced over it. Is chef-vault designed as solution to this problem of storing information you don't want to share? Does it replace encrypted_databags, or does it complement it? And if so, in what way?

Comment: It replaces the use of encrypted data bags and uses the PKI of chef that exists anyway. Based on search queries (e.g. all nodes having a certain role), you can store passwords (ending up in data bag items) that are only accessible by nodes having that role.